# Java - IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm not a beginner at Java, but nor am I an expert, which is why I am posting this for help/explanation. I've looked in many places across the internet, and there hasn't been an answer I'm looking for.

```
public class Driver {

public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> theData; // ArrayList to store the     ArrayList of values
final static int dataSize = 20; // length of the line of data in the inFile

/***
 * Read in the data from the inFile. Store the current line of values
 * in a temporary arraylist, then add that arraylist to theData, then
 * finally clear the temporary arraylist, and go to the next line of 
 * data.
 * 
 * @param inFile
 */
public static void getData(Scanner inFile) {
    ArrayList<Integer> tempArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int tempInt = 0;

    while (inFile.hasNext()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {
            tempInt = inFile.nextInt();
            tempArray.add(tempInt);
        }
        theData.add(tempArray);
        tempArray.clear();
    }
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inFile = null;
    theData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    System.out.println("BEGIN EXECUTION");

    try {
        inFile = new Scanner(new File("zin.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        getData(inFile);
    }
    System.out.println(theData.get(5).get(5)); // IndexOutOfBoundsException here
    System.out.println("END EXECUTION");
  }
```

}

I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException where I label it at. The interesting thing here is that when I was trying to figure this out, I tested to see if the method `getData` was working correctly, so as the method was iterating in the while loop in `getData` I printed out the size of the array-`theData`, AND the size of the arrays in the array `theData`, and what do you know, it returned a correct size and value. So basically when `getData` is called on, it works correctly and stores the values, but when I try to call on the values in `Main`, There is no values in the ArrayList.

I have a feeling this has something to do with when I clear the `tempArray` I used to add to `theData`. Any help will be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this code

```
theData.add(tempArray);
tempArray.clear();
```

the variable `tempArray` is a reference to an `ArrayList` object. You add that reference to the `theData` `ArrayList`. When you call `clear()` on it, you're clearing the same object whose reference you passed to `theData`. Instead of calling `clear()` just initialize a new `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thanks! Stupid mistake by me. The only reason I did it this way is because I did it this way for a similar project for C++(which allows you to do this).

Comment: @CraiGreen You're welcome. Take a few minutes to read [Is Java pass-by-reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference). Also, please consider accepting the answer if it covered everything.

Comment: I did - just had to wait a few minutes for StackOverflow to let me.